# Позиционирование текста в ToolStripMenuItem

Tags: c#, winforms

Я задал первому елементу меню висоту 60 и textalign = MiddleCenter
Но елемент просто игнорит свойство
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно разместить текст вертикально и горизонтально по центру

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отрисовать текст посередине элемента можно вручную, в событии `Paint`.

```
private void openToolStripMenuItem_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var item = sender as ToolStripItem;

    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, item.Text, item.Font, e.ClipRectangle, item.ForeColor
        //, TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter
        );
}
```

`TextRenderer` - это отрисовка с помощью GDI. По умолчанию задаётся форматирование по центру, как по вертикали, так и по горизонтали. Можно раскомментировать строку, чтобы задать форматирование самостоятельно.

Можно использовать отрисовку с помощью GDI+. Тут по умолчанию отрисовка выполняется в левом верхнем углу, поэтому задаём нужную.

```
private void openToolStripMenuItem_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var item = sender as ToolStripItem;

    var sf = new StringFormat();
    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

    e.Graphics.DrawString(item.Text, item.Font, Brushes.Black, e.ClipRectangle, sf);
}
```

В обоих случаях нужно отключить вывод текста элемента по умолчанию. Для этого можно задать свойство `DisplayStyle` в `None`.